# How to create a simple jQuery tabs without jQuery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I click on the tab it then displays the content that is associate. I'm using `#` to do it. Here is what I have tried, but I don't know how to do the switching part, Can someone help please?

So when click tab1 to show tab1 content, and click tab2 to show tab2 content and so on.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
    $('.tab-menu li a').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.tab-menu {
    padding: 0;
}
.tab-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tab-menu .active {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-menu">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="tab-1" class="tab-content">Content 1</p>
<p id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Content 2</p>
<p id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Content 3</p>
```

Edit, I prefer not to use jQuery UI or any plugins.

Comment: [Why re-invent the wheel](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)?

Comment: Why introduce another library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close here, just a couple things:

1) I would suggest applying the "active" class to the parent `<li>` so your highlighting will be simpler to get at

2) Use the `href` of the clicked link to switch out the content, and I would use a class to hide/show content, however I will provide jQuery following your example of using the `show()` and `hide()` method. Either approach would work.

The final jQuery would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab-content').slice(1).hide();
    $('.tab-menu li').eq(0).addClass('active');
    $('.tab-menu li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var content = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(content).show();
        $(content).siblings('.tab-content').hide();
    });
});
```

It's working in a fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/yscbeaxh/

Answer (score 2):

It's *really* hard to get tabs right. Your current code isn't too bad, but you will face hiccups eventually. I can't say what OTTOMH, but, you will ;).

For your current code, you need to take the `href` attribute from the click `li`, select the matching `p` (based on ID - it's handy that the `href` attr returns `#tab-1`, you can use that as your selector!), and show it. You'll also want to hide the other 'active' tabs, and remove the class from any 'active' li's too.

This code should do the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tab-content:not(:first)').hide();
    $('.tab-menu li a').click(function () {
        $('.tab-menu li a.active').removeClass('active');
        var tabDivId = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('p.tab-content').hide();
        $(tabDivId).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.tab-menu {
    padding: 0;
}
.tab-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.tab-menu .active {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-menu">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="tab-1" class="tab-content">Content 1</p>
<p id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Content 2</p>
<p id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Content 3</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very simple.

First I gave all the tabs a `display` of `none` and the active class `display:block;`
Than with jquery I take the `href` value of the `<a>` you clicked and than use that as the selector to add `class` active to the right tab.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2s7b6c7/2/)

html:

```
<ul class="tab-menu">
  <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs">
  <p id="tab-1" class="tab-content active">Content 1</p>
  <p id="tab-2" class="tab-content">Content 2</p>
  <p id="tab-3" class="tab-content">Content 3</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tab-menu {
  padding: 0;
}
.tab-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.tab-menu .active {
  background: yellow;
}
.tabs{
  width:50%;
}
.tabs > p{
 display:none;
}
.tabs .active{
 display:block;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.tab-menu li a').click(function () {
    $('.tab-menu li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    tab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tabs .active').removeClass('active');
    $(tab).addClass('active');
  });
});
```